# Using XML Schema to validate an XML Document

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Well, in the short version. Teacher gave us the review for test, which incorporates XML schema (which we have yet to go over in class). I'm reading the chapter, but its hard to figure out because the book only gives snippets of code at a time. So, I don't know how things should be placed in the bigger picture of things.

We have an XML Document that is like this

```
<enrollment>
  <semester>1128</semester>
  <student>
    <id>1000001</id>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <firstname>Joe</firstname>
    <courses>
      <course id="10001"/>
      <course id="10003"/>
    </courses>
    <tuition>200</tuition>
  </student>
</enrollment>
```

We must create an XML Schema that has these validatons.

1. there can be between zero and  10 courses
2. tuition must be greater than zero and less than 10,000.
3. create a custom type named CourseType that verifies that the course ID attribute contains exactly 5 digits.

This is my XML Schema Code I have so far (Not sure if it's correct). I feel very confident that the first two are correct. I don't understand the third one.

```
<xs:schema blah blah blah validation inputs>
<xs:element name="enrollment">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="courses">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="course"
          minOccurs="0"
          maxOccurs="10"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="tuition">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="10000"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Courses">
      <xs:complexType name ="Course">
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base ="xs:course ID">
          <xs:attribute name="id" type="CourseType">
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
       </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>  
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="CourseType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
   <xs:totalDigits value ="5"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions.

- You say the constraint on tuition is that it should be greater than zero and less then ten thousand.  Your declaration uses the minInclusive and maxInclusive facets, however, which allow the values zero and ten thousand; you might want to consider whether minExclusive and maxExclusive would do a better job of matching the requirement.
- The totalDigits facet ensures that the CourseType value can be written with five decimal digits or fewer, but it does not forbid the values `1`, `-12345`, or `0000000000001492`.  The constraint "contains exactly 5 digits" suggests a constraint on the lexical representation of the value.  Could you get what you need with the pattern facet?